# Pass class method as parameter to underscore.js

Tags: typescript, underscore.js

Here is my code:

```
export class DefectResource {

   setFormattedDateForDefect(defect) {
        defect.startFormatted = this.dateConverter.convertFromUnixDate(defect.start);
        defect.finishFormatted = this.dateConverter.convertFromUnixDate(defect.finish);
        return defect;
    };

    setFormattedDateForDefects(defects) {
        return _.map(angular.fromJson(defects), this.setFormattedDateForDefect);
    };
}
```

I am calling `setFormatedDateForDefects()` for collection of objects and this method must call `setFormattedDateForDefect()` for each method of this collection.  But don't call.

I know that the reason is `this` keyword which in this context is not an Object, but I don't know how to fix it.

How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the => syntax for method declarations which will ensure they are always bound to the "correct" this.

```
export class DefectResource {
    setFormattedDateForDefect = (defect) => {
        defect.startFormatted = this.dateConverter.convertFromUnixDate(defect.start);
        defect.finishFormatted = this.dateConverter.convertFromUnixDate(defect.finish);
        return defect;
    };

    setFormattedDateForDefects = (defects) => {
        return _.map(angular.fromJson(defects), this.setFormattedDateForDefect);
    };
}
```